# Looking to develop chat server that works in HTML5? Technology available?

Tags: html, chat

I was a big fan of AIM and live chat/buddy lists back in the day. With the rise of HTML5 and its use becoming more common in modern browsers, I'd like to develop an HTML5 messaging system.

What technologies do I have to look up? At the start, I won't care about the design (CSS), just functionality.

I'll most likely have a standard registration and store users in a MySQL Database.
Additionally, "friends" will also easily be stored in a database, populating a user's buddy list based on which user ID's he/she has marked as "friend".

The actual server and client connectivity is what most interests me. Is this technology available for HTML5 yet? Point me in the right direction and I'll be good to go!

Answer (score 2):

For the chat, you would probably like to look in to Websockets (as you talk about HTML5).

There are also examples like [this](http://chat.nodejs.org/) where NodeJS is used. To use node, you would have to run a node-server. For examples and more info: [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Hey, yea! I found a different but similar example on this page: http://html5demos.com/web-socket. You can see my comments on it in the post written by Tim Brown :]

Answer (score 1):

I think the [websockets API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) will be your first port of call for a messaging app in HTML5. You'll be wanting the server to notify the client rather than the client poll or rely on callbacks and this would be the start i think.

However, I don't think this is very well supported in even the most modern browser. In fact i believe [firefox and opera have pulled support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support) because of security concerns.

I haven't done any work in this myself but just though it looked interesting stuff. So I guess I just wish you luck with your dev. Exciting cutting edge stuff I think.

Comment: yea I found this example http://html5demos.com/web-socket which seems to work well. Would just need to modify it to require some type of secure authentication as well as remove the timeout/disconnect settings which seem to be in place. After that, additional features could be added, but have to remember to start small!

Comment: That looks good. I'd be interested to know which browsers actually support it in reality (rather than what they claim to do). I might do a bit of browser upgrading and give it a go.