# How to implement a chat application without using javascript timeout?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to implement a chat application but I don't want to use timeout because it checks every few seconds.  Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *javascript timeout*, do you mean `setTimeout()`? Also, have you begun writing some part of the application?

Comment: yes i am talking about setInterval()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax to call to a php page that will hang until there is something new and then it sends that to the client, and after the ajax uses what it got, it can make another request to that page, that will hang again. This way you trade the requests to the server for server processing time. You can use usleep, and a while loop to keep the page alive, and don't forget to set the execution time limit of page.

EDIT 1:

Well, I will suppose that you have a function to send data (I will call it `request`), and asynchronously waiting for a response, and you linked a function to execute on response. Let's call that function `listen`.

And another function `send` that sends the replies of user, or anything else. Both `send` and `listen` will request the same page, one with no `POST` or `GET` data (`listen`), and one with `POST` data containing the replies or other thing.

The initial request will be done with `listen`, or when you want to manually start the listener, and after a response. The other one is called anytime you send something.

What is important is the php code.

If you are working in a linux environment you can use a lot of things like os signals, but in general we can use while, and usleep, so that we do not kill the server.

and now:

```
<?php

// code for mysql
if(isset($_POST))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (user,instance,date,reply) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user']."','room','etc','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply'])."')");
    $_SESSION['last_reply_id'] = mysql_insert_id();
}

while(true)
{
    $rez = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > '".$_SESSION['last_reply_id']."' ORDER BY `id` DESC");

    $repls = array();

    if(count($rez))
    {
        while($rez = mysql_fetch_array($rez))
        {
            $repls[] = $rez;
        }
        $_SESSION['last_reply_id'] = $repls[0]['id'];
        echo json_encode($repls);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        usleep(200000);
    }
}
?>
```

Now, you first call `listen`, that will wait until it echoes an brake the loop, and when it does, you use the result, and then you call `listen` again. In case you want to send something, you use `send`, that must brake the previous request and make a new one, that after it writes the data will start the listener. And so on, I hope you got the idea, tell me if you want to clarify it a bit.

And do not forget to use `set_time_limit(0);` at the start of the page.

I might be a bit off, and need to review this code, but this is the main idea.

Comment: hey i tried this 
but this is not allow that user to send another request

Comment: @BhavikPatel you might have some problems configuring the server, and watch out with session, you must always kill the listener page before attempting to make another request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, any method requires something to check a database every few seconds or however long the increment you want.
The only other method in Javascript is a setInterval(code, time) where the code is executed every "time".
 
Just for clarification, this is if you want your chat to automatically update without reloading the page.

Comment: yea i implemented in this way but i am finding some other method to do this

Answer (score 0):

Similar questions has been up several times before. I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546042/looking-to-develop-chat-server-that-works-in-html5-technology-available/8546088#8546088) a couple of days ago, that suggest either Websocket or Node.js. Maybe that can get you started.